# DATE型のレコードを取得しましたが、0020年となってしまう。

Tags: sql, oracle

TESTTABLE内のDATE型のHIDUKE(20-07-21)を取得し、2020/07/21としたいのですが、0020/07/21になってしまいます。

```
select to_char(HIDUKE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') from TESTTABLE;
```

NLS_DATE_FORMATはRR-MMDDです。

その他に何か設定などがあるのでしょうか？ご教授いただければ幸いです。

なお、以下のクエリであれば2020/07/21にて取得することが可能でした。（DATE型をDATE型ってよく分かりませんが…）

```
select to_char(to_date(HIDUKE, 'RRRR/MM/DD'), YYYY/MM/DD) from TESTTABLE;
```

Comment: この結果はSQL*Plusで実行した結果でしょうか？HIDUKEの型(des TESTTABLEの結果)は何でしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[Oracleの日付変換トラブル（その後）](http://you-sk.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/07/08/140730), [Oracleの日付書式"RR"と"YY"は4桁表記にも適用できる](https://taityo-diary.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/11/05/081326), [書式モデル(日付)](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/datetime-format-element.html)